# Mapeamento Eloquent?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Existe alguma maneira de mapear uma chave estrangeira de uma `database` fora do meu `default database` no Laravel Eloquent?

Exemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Banco1.Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City int(11),

    CONSTRAINT FK_City FOREIGN KEY (City)     
      REFERENCES Banco2.City (City)     
      ON NO_ACTION    
      ON NO_ACTION
    )
);
```

Comment: E ai deu certo??? a reposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devem existir várias maneiras de se fazer isso, irei responder com uso que creio ser a melhor forma,

Adicione a segunda conexão no no seu `config/database.php`:

```
'mysql_secondary' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('SECOND_DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('SECOND_DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('SECOND_DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
    'username' => env('SECOND_DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
    'password' => env('SECOND_DB_PASSWORD', 'pass'),
    'unix_socket' => env('SECOND_DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => 'InnoDB',
],
```

Com isso você já consegue conectar a 2 bancos, o `default` e o `mysql_secondary`.

> Para usar determinar a qual banco você está conectado basta usar o método estático: `DB::connection('mysql_secondary');`, passando como parâmetro o nome da conexão do banco configurado no **database.php**

Crie o migration e dentro da função `up():`

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Persons', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('PersonID');
            $table->string('LastName', 255);
            $table->string('FirstName', 255);
            $table->string('Address', 255);
            $table->integer('City');
        });

        Schema::table('Persons', function($table) {
            $db = \DB::connection('mysql_secondary')->getDatabaseName();
            $table->foreign('City', 'FK_City')
            ->references('City')->on($db . '.City');            
        });
    }
```

Essa função está criando a tabela e logo após definido a FK.

> **OBS.:** é necessário que as tabelas estejam definida como **InnoDB**

Caso queria, agora basta você fazer os relacionamentos **belongsTo** dentro do seu model.

Esse procedimento foi testado no **Laravel 5.7** com **PHP 7.2** e **Mysql 5.7**.

**[Referencia 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28950070/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-foreign-key-in-a-different-database-in-laravel), [Referencia 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25952348/laravel-run-migrations-on-another-database).**